# Php mysqli_query() error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying fetch data from Database and check if the returned result is empty or not. This is my code.

```
<?php
require "init1.php";

$jsonObject = $_GET["UserDetails"];
$obj = json_decode($jsonObject);

$email = $obj->Email;
$password = $obj->Password;
$Username = $obj->Username;
$Sex = $obj->Sex;

$timestamp = strtotime($obj->BirthDay);
$BirthDay = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);

$sql = "select * from Registered_Users where Username='$Username' or Email='$Email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $myclass = new stdClass();
    $myclass->status = "Not Ok";

    echo json_encode($myclass);

} else {

    try {
        $sql_query = "insert into Registered_Users (Email, Password, BirthDay, Sex, Username) values('$email', '$password', '$BirthDay', '$Sex', '$Username')";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)) {
            $obj1 = new stdClass();
            $obj1->status = "Ok";
            echo json_encode($obj1);
        } else {
            $obj1 = new stdClass();
            $obj1->status = "Not Ok";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Can i know whats wrong with my above code, What's happening is i am checking if the username or email is present in the Database if so, It will print `not ok` else it will print `ok` . But when i run the code even if the $result is greater than  it's echoing `ok`, when i run the same code second time it says `NOT OK`. Can some one tell me what's wrong .

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure your `$con` is correct?

Comment: check once with mysqli error

Comment: Use prepared statements!

Comment: Kindly, add your whole code.

Comment: i dont think prepared statements will make any difference

Comment: PS will not solve this problem but others in futures ;). So what's happens when you do this `mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` ?

Comment: its not throwing any error! should i put the code in try catch block?

Comment: Wooow, you declare `$email` but use `$Email` at query.

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable name $Email and use $email

```
$sql = "select * from Registered_Users where Username='$Username' or Email='$email'";
```